# What happens if you set role = "" on an HTML element?

Tags: reactjs, roles

I am using ReactJS to create a generic wrapper component. I want to pass in `role` as a `propType` and on my rendered div have something like `<div role={role}>`.

My question is, what if a role isn't passed in and I end up with `<div role="">`?  Will that mess up screen readers, etc.?

I don't want to make it a required prop because this is just a generic wrapper div and not all elements will have a role.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it shouldn't mess anything up.

As far as a browser is concerned, there's not really any difference between `<div role="">` and `<div>`

Comment: perfect, thanks!  Can the same be said for aria attributes so aria-expanded = "" is fine too?

Comment: @PaulFabbroni the same should apply to any HTML attribute.